# From module import string as module

Tags: python, import, python-import

I need to import DataFrame as string from pandas.

```
import importlib
import pandas
full_module_name = "DataFrame"
mymodule = importlib.import_module(pandas.full_module_name)
```

or

```
import importlib
full_module_name = "pandas.DataFrame"
mymodule = importlib.import_module(full_module_name)
```

Comment: `getattr(pandas, full_module_name)`?

Comment: Yes. And if I cant import pandas, getattr("pandas", full_module_name) dont work. Who can I do it?

Comment: What do you want to happen if importing pandas fails?

Comment: I just edited my question! Please check!